# Why won't my image fill the header section of my website (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I've looked at W3C and tried to add an image to my header. This exact code works on another site I'm working on so I can't figure out why the code won't work here. One difference between the two is this site is a php file the other is straight up html.

My html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang = "en">

<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <title>User Based Web Design</title>
    <!--title displayed in the tab, search-able title of the page-->

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Reset.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Home Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Navigation Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Footer Styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header> <!--start visible header section-->
        <h1>Laura Pohl</h1>
        <h2>User Based Web Design</h2>
    </header> <!--end visible header section-->
```

my css:

```
header {
    background-image: url('Images/banner_option1.jpg'); /*sets background to the image in ""*/
    height: 100%;/*fills 100% of the vertical header section*/
    background-size: cover;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: what "don't work" means in the context? What should be the expected result?

Comment: PHP cannot change the way things are displayed. I suggest you remove that tag.

Comment: The parent of an element with `height: 100%` must have a defined height.

Comment: Doesn't work = image doesn't show. Which tag are you suggesting I remove? Isn't the height defined by the contents?

Comment: @Laura if the image isn't showing at all, it's probably a path issue. Ensure the file path to the image is correct

Comment: @RachelGallen the image isn't showing at all, but when use the same file path to add the image straight into the html, the image appears so I don't think it is a file path issue. Thanks Though!

Comment: Can you try, whether it works, when you add `../` in front of the image URL in the CSS?

Comment: @reinstate Monica--thanks for the suggestion but it still doesn't work :(